# Testing jquery change for simple checkbox function

Tags: jquery, testing, coffeescript, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

First, I just wanted to say that the below code is working in reality.  It is only failing in the jasmine spec.  The function is very simple.  When the check box with id "check_all" is selected, select all the other check boxes as well.

When I run the test, everything up to and including expect #check_all to be true passes as expected.  I'm having trouble understanding however why all my expectations are not passing.  Any advice?

Function:

```
window.check_all = () ->
  $('#check_all').change(->
    if $('#check_all').is(':checked')
      $('.checkbox').attr('checked', 'checked')
    else
      $('.checkbox').removeAttr('checked')
  )
$(check_all)
```

Test:

```
describe 'checkbox', ->
  beforeEach ->
    loadFixtures 'checkbox'
  describe 'check_all', ->
    it 'checks all the checkboxes if check_all is checked', ->
      expect($('#check_all').is(':checked')).toBeFalsy()
      expect($('#question_1').is(':checked')).toBeFalsy()
      expect($('#question_2').is(':checked')).toBeFalsy()
      expect($('#question_3').is(':checked')).toBeFalsy()
      expect($('#question_4').is(':checked')).toBeFalsy()
      expect($('#question_5').is(':checked')).toBeFalsy()

      $('#check_all').attr('checked', 'checked')
      $('#check_all').change()

      expect($('#check_all').is(':checked')).toBeTruthy()
      expect($('#question_1').is(':checked')).toBeTruthy()
      expect($('#question_2').is(':checked')).toBeTruthy()
      expect($('#question_3').is(':checked')).toBeTruthy()
      expect($('#question_4').is(':checked')).toBeTruthy()
      expect($('#question_5').is(':checked')).toBeTruthy()
```

Fixture:

```
<p class="small gray"><input type="checkbox" name="check_all" id="check_all"> Select All</p>
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="" method="post">
    <ul class="library_questions">
        <li>
            <input class="checkbox" id="question_1" name="question[]" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
            Template Q1
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="checkbox" id="question_2" name="question[]" type="checkbox" value="2"/>
            Template Q2
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="checkbox" id="question_3" name="question[]" type="checkbox" value="3"/>
            Template Q3
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="checkbox" id="question_4" name="question[]" type="checkbox" value="4"/>
            Template Q4
        </li>
        <li>
            <input class="checkbox" id="question_5" name="question[]" type="checkbox" value="5"/>
            Instructions
        </li>
    </ul>
    <input class="purple submit_button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you jsFiddle  some of it out. Maybe extend [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/hgJbv/) I started getting "check_all" to work correctly and making better use of jQuery than what i see in your example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running `check_all` from the `$` function, meaning that it runs after the document ready event. I'm guessing that your test runs sooner, which is why triggering the `change` event doesn't affect the checkboxes. So, either:

1. Put your tests in the `$` wrapper, or
2. Put the script that defines `check_all` in your page at the end of the `<body>`. Then you don't need to use the `$` wrapper at all.

A third option would be to bind a `change` event handler on an ancestor of `#check_all` instead. For instance,

```
$(document).on('change', '#check_all', -> ...)
```

(Before jQuery 1.7, you'd use `live` instead of `on`.) That way, even if your script ran from the `<head>`, you still wouldn't need the `$` wrapper.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but none of these options resulted in the test passing.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the issue... try running `window.checkAll()` from the top of `describe 'check_all', ->`.